# jQuery: live function for initializing plugins

Tags: jquery, widget, live

i've made some little widget-plugins which are getting applied to eg. a textbox
like $("input.txtbox").myTextbox();

now i'm using ajax for dynamically loading content and i was wondering:
is there a way to use jquery's live function for auto-applying that plugin to each textbox which will be loaded via ajax?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `.live()` but you can set up a global [`ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess) or [`ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete) handler.

```
$.ajaxSuccess(function ()
{
    $('input.txtbox').myTextbox();
});
```

You might want to make this more efficient by not re-initializing the plugin on inputs which already have been initialized; something like

```
$.ajaxSuccess(function ()
{
    $('input.txtbox:not(.myTextbox)').myTextbox().addClass('myTextbox');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are actually events triggered when the DOM structure is modified. Whenever a new textbox is created and inserted into the document, you could react to bind your plugin initialization code. The events in question for you purpose are DOMNodeInserted (node was added a a child node to another element) and DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument (node was initially inserted into document).

Note that availability of these events is not guaranteed / event is not supported by all browsers. Thus you'd need to check this with your targeted browsers / implementations and probably use Matt's approach to have it working across browsers.

Assuming your targeted browsers support the events, you'd do something similar to:

```
$(document).live('DOMNodeInserted', function(e){
    // Get inserted node from event and initialize your plugin if the element is initially seen
});
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't support this by default. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/4tVAx/ It'd have to be `document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false);`

Comment: You're right. jQuery does not currently seem to support binding this event with live. If bound using bind the handler gets called as expected.
See the updated test case http://jsfiddle.net/4tVAx/1/